# difference between ${CDR(duration)} and ${CDR(billsec)} in asterisk dialplan

Tags: asterisk, record, phone-call

I want to get the duration of the call but confused which variable to use

**${CDR(duration)}**  or

**${CDR(billsec)}**

[Here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/CDR+Variables) it is not clear from when ${CDR(duration)}  records the time

**So which should i use ${CDR(duration)} or ${CDR(billsec)} ?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let say call come in and no answer for X second, after that answered, after that Y seconds speaks/play something and hang up.

So duration will be X + Y, while billsec(time to be billed) will be Y.

CDR(billsec) is answered time or time to be billed, without call setup time(post-dial delay).

Answer (score 5):

BillSec is "how long was the call off hook" ... a common metric for things like LD billing or "usage minutes".

Duration is "how long from start to finish, including switching delays and redirections" ... note that technically `Duration can be >0` while `BillSec == 0,` if the call was routed but not answered.

Since you don't say what you need to know the value *for*, it's hard to tell you which version you need.