# how can i show Aterisk active call dutation only call time?

Tags: asterisk

When get debug on asterisk 1.8 my result was something like this

i tried "**core show channels verbose**" this command to get output about active call. its show me call duration.

all result show well but my problem is i want to show only call time after a call answered.

**Total Duration = invite time + ringing time + call time**

but i want to show only call time

**Total Duration = only call time**

So what i need to do to get my result.

Thanks.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860456/difference-between-cdrduration-and-cdrbillsec-in-asterisk-dialplan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of getting call time using "core show channels verbose" command.
You need to monitor call events to get information about on going calls and their exact call duration.